# Изменение размера иконки svg через css

Tags: css, wordpress, svg

Есть сайт на WordPress и тема Appointment. Для того чтобы вставить свои иконки вместо Font-Awesome использовал следующий код в таблице стилей, но изменить размер иконки не получается:

```
.fa-mobile-phone: {
  content:url("https://multiservis.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Иконки-100х100.svg") !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконки надо задавать примерно так:

```css
.fa-mobile-phone {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.fa-mobile-phone:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://multiservis.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Иконки-100х100.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="fa-mobile-phone">Телефон</div>
```

Comment: Вы посмотрите, КАК я объявил css. Читайте ответ внимательно. Вместо `content: url` в моём ответе что?

Comment: я переопредиляю вывод иконки из шрифта а не создаю свою иконку

Comment: Какие блоки div в css - что за чушь. Или вам не нравится display: inline-block? Тогда вы плохо знаете css. Вы сниппет видите? Он работает. Измените определения стиля в https://multiservis.online/wp-content/themes/appointment/style.css и все получится.

Comment: Вот я в dev tools примерно накидал http://take.ms/0b653. Как видите, все работает на вашем сайте. Прежде чем спорить, над попробовать применить ответ.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, очевидно, у пользователя мало опыта в данной сфере

Comment: @St1myL когда мало опыта, надо пробовать сначала, что предлагают более опытные пользователи, а потом спорить и высказывать мнения насчет div в css.

Comment: 1. Я не вижу моего кода на сайте вообще. 2. Отключите модуль pagespeed при разработке, он кеширует все так, что не разобраться. 3. Я вам показал общее направление действия - вместо content: url надо content: block и background с размерами. Вы же не ожидаете, что я тут за вас буду ваш сайт настраивать? По правилам сообщества, никаких внешних ссылок вообще не допускается. Вы должны создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Где вот тут мой код на вашем сайте? http://take.ms/LYjmp

Comment: Спасибо за решение проблемы( В первоначальном виде ваше решение действительно не работает)

Comment: Вот лишь бы сказать что-то. Да оно работает и в первоначальном, и в любом другом виде. И мой сниппет в вопросе это демонстрирует. То, что решение надо подправить на вашем конкретном сайте - вполне возможно. Но по правилам сообщества, все, что вне вопроса, не рассматривается. Вы задали вопрос - я вам ответил и указал на причину - неправильно делать content: url